# Leitura arquivo em C

Tags: c, arquivo

Ttenho a seguinte estrutura para leitura de cada linha de um arquivo:

```
fclose(arq); // fecha o arquivo para em seguida abri-lo em modo leitura apenas
arq = fopen(url, "r");
if(arq == NULL) {
    printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
} else {
    system("cls");
    printf("\n **************************************** NOME DA EMPRESA - LISTA DE CLIENTES ****************************************\n\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    while (fgets(linha, TAM_BUFFER, arq)) { // lê cada linha do arquivo por vez, cada linha está na variável buffer
        printf("Cliente %d:\n", idx);
        idx++;
        fflush(stdin);
        // para cada linha capturada, atribui um valor a variável, para em seguida fazer a impressão
        fscanf(arq, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]\n", cpf, nome, cnh, endereco, contato, passaporte, idoneo);
```

Problemas:

1. a primeira linha não é impressa (acredito que o programa está lendo
   um ENTER e passa para a segunda linha, só não vejo onde);
2. após a impressão da primeira linha (que na verdade é a segunda), o
   CPF do terceiro cliente é impresso isoladamente;
3. os dados do terceiro cliente não são impressos, daí pula para o
   quarto cliente, como, assim como o segundo cliente, os dados são
   impressos corretamente.

Essa sequência de problemas é o padrão da resposta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cada campo no arquivo está separado por vírgula, como pode ser notado no código acima.

Alguém pode me confirmar o famigerado ENTER que está sendo lido em algum ponto que não consigo detectar? Ou vê algum outro erro?

Comment: Tem como postar a saída como texto? Não consigo ver daqui do meu celular

Comment: Você deve ter percebido que não está lendo todos os clientes ímpares, correto? Isso acontece porque você está consumindo o arquivo em dois pontos distintos

Comment: Você quer dizer no fgets e no fscanf?

Comment: Sim. Estou escrevendo uma resposta detalhando isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para começar, como você não está tocando na `stdin`, você não precisa dar um `fflush` nela.

Outra coisa: usar `fgets` fará com que o ponteiro de leitura do arquivo seja movido para frente. Usar `fscanf` logo em seguida não conseguirá usar esse dados, pois eles já foram consumidos!

Como resolver isso? Tem algumas maneiras...

> Como a entrada não está disponível, não posso tentar rodar e verificar se *realmente* faz sentido o código; fiz o que pude com os dados fornecidos

## Retorno do `fscanf`

A função `scanf` e suas irmãs retornam um inteiro. O que esse inteiro quer dizer? Simples, quantos argumentos foram lidos. Essa função retorna a quantidade de caracteres consumidos pela leitura, ou negativo caso não consiga ler nada. Você pode encontrar a documentação [aqui](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm).

> eu não tenho certeza em relação a argumentos do tipo `%*`

Isso quer dizer que a função pode ser o parâmetro do `while`. De modo geral, assumindo que seu `fscanf` está correto:

```
while (fscanf(arq, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]\n", cpf, nome, cnh, endereco, contato, passaporte, idoneo) > 0) { // tenta ler, se possível é um cliente válido
        printf("Cliente %d:\n", idx);
        idx++;
        // para cada linha capturada, atribui um valor a variável, para em seguida fazer a impressão
        // resto do seu código
```

## `sscanf`, leitura de uma string

Outra alternativa é manter o `fgets` e alterar a fonte de leitura. Uma das funções da família `scanf` é o `sscanf`:

- `scanf` faz leitura da entrada padrão
- `fscanf` faz leitura de um arquivo dado
- `sscanf` faz leitura de uma string

O resto do código continua **idêntico**, só troque o `fscanf` por isso:

```
sscanf(linha, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]\n", cpf, nome, cnh, endereco, contato, passaporte, idoneo);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @Ângelo por nada! As informações que eu obtive através de seu texto eram parciais, mas espero que tenham sido suficiente para dar uma luz no seu problema