# Arquivo Em linguagem C

Tags: c

Tenho Um arquivo Nesse seguinte formato:

https://mega.nz/#!DwxXRIzK (link para download do arquivo ler);

```
[105][32][55][10][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][82][101][108][101][97][115][101]...
```

preciso fazer a leitura dos dados nesse formato:

```
105 32 55 10 32 32 32 32 32...[32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][82][101][108][101][97][115][101]...
```

eu estou usando o treicho de código:

```
while( c != EOF) {

    fscanf(ler, "%c", &c);
    fscanf(ler, "%d", &num);
    fscanf(ler, "%c", &a);

    fprintf(traduzido, "%d ", num);

}
```

mas o looping nunca se encerra, também estou usando este:

```
while(fscanf(ler, "%c", &c)  && fscanf(ler, "%d", &num)   &&   fscanf(ler, "%c", &a)   != EOF) {

    fprintf(traduzido, "%d ", num);

}
```

mas ele não para de ler o arquivo, sempre passa de duas a tres linhas.

Qual o erro e porque do erro? Como posso fazer a leitura desse arquivo e deixar no jeito que quero, se tiver uma maneira mais fácil?

Olha o código por completo:

```
int main(void)

int num;
char c;

FILE *ler;
FILE *traduzido;

ler = fopen("readme.code.txt", "r");
traduzido = fopen("traduzido.txt", "w");

if(ler == NULL || traduzido == NULL) {
    printf("Erro Na aberura do Arquivo");
}

while(1) {
    if (fscanf(ler, "%c", &c) <= 0){
        break;
    }

    fscanf(ler, "%d", &num);
    fscanf(ler, "%c", &c);

    fprintf(traduzido,"%d ", num);
}

while(fscanf(traduzido, "%d", &num) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", num);
}
system("pause");
```

Comment: O correto é verificar a saída do `scanf`. Eu já respondi uma pergunta semelhante à essa, mas obviamente está perdida no mar de respostas.

Comment: Nesta resposta eu falo um pouco sobre o retorno do `scanf`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/253415/64969; creio que vá ajudar

Comment: Por sinal, esse fluxo poderia ser tratado como o fluxograma dessa questão: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/251865/64969; "a": leitura, "b": se aconteceu o fim do arquivo, termina o loop

Comment: Dei uma olhada, mas consigo, faço a leitura até o ultimo item do arquivo mais ai para ali, fica em um looping

Comment: `while( fscanf(ler,"%c", &c) != EOF ){
            
        fscanf(ler, "%d", &num);
        fscanf(ler, "%c", &c);
        fprintf(traduzido, "%d ", num);

    }` a porcaria desse código não deveria parar  ? ele fica em looping

Comment: Calma, jovem. Na resposta, eu pus na condição se o retorno fosse positivo. Na documentação linkada, tem dizendo que, caso desse erro, retornaria um valor negativo (não especificando qual valor negativo). No caso, `EOF` é um valor negativo possível em 2 bilhões existentes. Talvez trocar essa diferença por um `> 0` ou `>= 0` (eu não lembro o que o retorno 0 quer dizer...) seja melhor

Comment: O Problema é que nunca Retorna < 0, sempre positivo, eu sinceramente não sei o problema da minha verificação, ja to irado aqui, não vai nunca

Comment: As reticências são literais ou são apenas um recurso estilístico para indicar que pode ter mais coisa? Se for a segunda opção, tente fazer um exemplo de entrada e saída mínimos para tentarmos reproduzir. Por exemplo, com 3 números seria o suficiente

Comment: Jura que subiu o arquivo no mega uploads? Por que não ter um exemplo menor e viável?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `fscanf` devolve:

- A quantidade de elementos lidos e atribuídos a variáveis
- `0` se não conseguiu associar nenhum elemento
- `EOF`, que corresponde a `-1` caso tenha chegado ao fim do arquivo

Nesse caso e assumindo que a estrutura do seu arquivo é sempre `[numero]` pode testar especificamente por valores iguais ou inferiores a `0` no primeiro `fscanf`:

```
while(1) { //agora while infinito
    if (fscanf(ler, "%c", &c) <= 0){
        break; //se não conseguiu ler o próximo [ termina o while
    }

    fscanf(ler, "%d", &num);
    fscanf(ler, "%c", &c);

    fprintf(traduzido, "%d ", num);
}
```

Note que pode usar a mesma variável `c` pois não está a fazer nada com ela.

Se quiser jogar pelo seguro, e ficar resistente a alterações nos formatos pode testar todos os `fscanf`:

```
while(1) {
    if (fscanf(ler, "%c", &c) <= 0 ||  
        fscanf(ler, "%d", &num) <= 0 || 
        fscanf(ler, "%c", &c) <= 0){
        break;
    }

    fprintf(traduzido, "%d ", num);
}
```

Teste do programa trocando `fprintf` por `printf` para ser mais fácil de ver:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teste com o arquivo sugerido `readme.code.txt` :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edit**:

Em relação ao resto do programa que tem o problema está na leitura de um ficheiro que foi aberto para escrita.

Feche o ficheiro `traduzido` depois de escrever e abra-o de novo para leitura:

```
while(1) {
    if (fscanf(ler, "%c", &c) <= 0){
        break;
    }

    fscanf(ler, "%d", &num);
    fscanf(ler, "%c", &c);

    fprintf(traduzido,"%d ", num);
}

fclose(traduzido); //fechar a escrita
traduzido = fopen("traduzido.txt", "r"); //agora abrir para leitura

while(fscanf(traduzido, "%d", &num) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", num);
}
```

No entanto mais eficiente era simplesmente escrever o conteúdo do que está a ser lido diretamente na tela, em vez de utilizar o arquivo `traducao` para escrever e depois para ler:

```
while(1) {
    if (fscanf(ler, "%c", &c) <= 0){
        break;
    }

    fscanf(ler, "%d", &num);
    fscanf(ler, "%c", &c);

    fprintf(traduzido,"%d ", num); //grava no arquivo a tradução
    printf("%c",num); //e simultaneamente escreve na tela a conversão
}
```

Fica bem mais eficiente e simples.

Comment: Hmmmm, lembrei de algo interessante.. `%*c` lê a informação e a descarta, portanto não precisaria nem colocar a variável `c` em jogo

Comment: O problema é que passa, por exemplo, ele lê até o ultimo numero mais ai começa a vim alguns repetidos, ele para de ler o arquivo e está vindo lixo da memoria

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Sim é de facto uma opção interessante que otimiza ainda mais os recursos

Comment: @Fernando O arquivo tem quebras de linha ? Como está exatamente o conteudo do arquivo?

Comment: Sem quebra de linha, esse é o final do arquivo, [101][100][46]... já o arquivo traduzido vem assim ->  101 100 46  99 111 109 47 100 101 108... ele para depois de umas 10 linhas, tipo no fina do arquivo ler, tem um espaço, por exe, [101][100][46]...............................................

Comment: @Fernando Testei com o `[105][32][55][10][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][32][82][101][108][101][97][115][101]` que estava na pergunta e funcionou na perfeição. Pode colocar na pergunta o conteúdo exato do arquivo, para que eu possa testar e reproduzir o problema ?

Comment: Coloquei um link com o arquivo

Comment: @Fernando pede chave para aceder ao arquivo, melhor talvez colocar no pastebin ou outra alternativa semelhante.

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!blAGiBrD!aYphUoyfUbwlF8wiAu25QsewmE2aD0merkIpWapDt_Y
 tenta esse

Comment: @Fernando funcionou bem. Há outra coisa qualquer que não deve estar a fazer corretamente, talvez no resto do programa. Se quiser posso incluir um print também da execução com esse arquivo.

Comment: Poste sim então, deve ser problema aqui se ai deu certo

Comment: @Fernando Veja na minha edição como funcionou. Note no entanto que escrevendo cada numero lido na tela, ainda leva 4 segundos até terminar.

Comment: Estou tentando resolver aqui, deixa eu verificar o codigo dnv, tenta imprimir assim prinf("%c", num)   isso ai é um texto, se tiver curiosidade pra ver '-'

Comment: Olhe o meu código lá na pergunta, me ajuda a achar o erro ?

Comment: @Fernando Editei a resposta, já contemplando o código que colocou.

Comment: Cara eu te amo, vlw mesmo, era só aquilo e eu não entendia, vlw pela paciência, verdade, poderia imprimir direto lá... mas de qualquer jeito eu teria que ler depois, essa só foi a primeira parte, tenho mas umas duas, agora a missão é colocar o numero de linha

Comment: Vou fazer uma resposta baseada na sua mesclando com os resultados que obtive neste experimento: https://ideone.com/3WFf96

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Parece me uma boa ideia. Quanto mais respostas, mais possíveis soluções e mais conteúdo oferecemos à comunidade! :)

Comment: Agora obtive o resultado que eu queria: https://ideone.com/FeohUm ; sabia que era possível ignorar marcas de formatação de uma entrada arbitrária através do `scanf`

Answer (score 3):

Vim aqui apenas mostrar demais possibilidades à [resposta do @Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/257244/64969), usando recursos do `scanf` para remover essa formatação.

Para começar, achei estranho ler o valor de um caracter em uma variável temporária para ignorar. Lembrei então que em algum lugar eu havia visto algo sobre a leitura que não preenchia os valores (vide [documentação](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm)), a leitura indicada pelo modificador `*`; por exemplo, `scanf("%*c")` vai ler um caracter da entrada e ignorá-lo. Então, fiz um teste sobre essa leitura ignorando caracteres:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;

    scanf("%*c%d%*c", &i);
    printf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Para a entrada `[123]`, o resultado foi `123`, conforme o esperado.

Então eu me lembrei de que é possível ignorar a formatação propriamente dita da entrada. Basta colocar os caracteres desejados a serem ignorados à esquerda antes do `%d`, e os caracteres a serem ignorados à direita após o `%d`. No caso, o formato seria  `[%d]`, porque desejo ignorar o **abre colchetes `[`** à esquerda e o **fecha colchetes `]`** à direita:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;

    scanf(" [%d]", &i);
    printf("%d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Testei para a entrada `[145]`, obtendo `145` como saída. Se prestar atenção, eu pus um espaço no começo da string de formato para evitar conflitos com quebras de linhas, pois meu teste envolvia um número entre colchetes por linha. Você pode ver o meu teste completo no [ideone](https://ideone.com/FeohUm).

Então, isso significa que a leitura proposta pelo @Isac poderia ser substituído por uma dessas opções.

Original:

```
while(1) {
    if (fscanf(ler, "%c", &c) <= 0){
        break;
    }

    fscanf(ler, "%d", &num);
    fscanf(ler, "%c", &c);

    fprintf(traduzido,"%d ", num); //grava no arquivo a tradução
    printf("%c",num); //e simultaneamente escreve na tela a conversão
}
```

Proposta 1, com `%*c`:

```
while(1) {
    if (fscanf(ler, "%*c%d%*c", &num) <= 0){
        break;
    }

    fprintf(traduzido,"%d ", num); //grava no arquivo a tradução
    printf("%c",num); //e simultaneamente escreve na tela a conversão
}
```

Proposta 2, com string de formatação ignorando os colchetes:

```
while(1) {
    if (fscanf(ler, "[%d]", &num) <= 0){
        break;
    }

    fprintf(traduzido,"%d ", num); //grava no arquivo a tradução
    printf("%c",num); //e simultaneamente escreve na tela a conversão
}
```

Comment: Todos os métodos funcionam como esperado,  esse último ["%d"]  provavelmente é o mais eficiente, já que não precisa de mais variáveis e leitura, obrigado pela ajuda também

Comment: Falar de eficiência é complicado, teria de testar bastante... posso tentar atualizar depois essa resposta com um _corpus_ de teste adequado para o  _benchmark_

Comment: Não precisa desse trabalho todo não, rlx

Comment: Moço sei que já estou pedindo demais, mas não tem como tu me dar uma luz, eu estou tentando fazer isso olha [https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/VxB5_DGTFpef1uuwhFreh0cqabgfnC5EyWTSk1PourwcHyY9WCGQuD5Y-eGRQo6n_qsUmYhWdQPJOXeQHicB=w1680-h917]  mas não consigo fazer com que fique só na primeira linha, eu to gerando 80 a 140 mb de texto, nada ver o que eu estou fazendo. (coloquei a foto do google Drive)

Comment: Moço, pela sua descrição deu uma preguiça de ver... sem falar que meu computador não tá ajudando em nada, nem consigo trabalhar sem precisar reiniciar a cada 30 min

Comment: Tudo certo então

Comment: Consegui, mó facim